# In Laravel it take different table row id that is not availabe in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I truncate the table and storing data to table it store from 1
but when I edit or view this entry it takes different id
like as:

**database entry**[image]
and when **I retrieve this row then result is:** 
[image]

query : `$user_id =Auth::id();

```
    $company_detail = DB::table('companies')
                        ->select('companies.*','job_locations.*')
                        ->where('companies.id',$id)
                        ->where('companies.user_account_id',$user_id)
                        ->join('job_locations', 'companies.location_id', '=', 'job_locations.id')
                        ->first()`
```

please forget if any typo or explanation error.

Thank You

Comment: *"I retrieve this row then result is:"* - Show the code you're using to retrieve this record...

Comment: `$user_id =Auth::id();

        $company_detail = DB::table('companies')
                            ->select('companies.*','job_locations.*')
                            ->where('companies.id',$id)
                            ->where('companies.user_account_id',$user_id)
                            ->join('job_locations', 'companies.location_id', '=', 'job_locations.id')
                            ->first()`

Comment: I guess it is id from ```job_locations.*```

Comment: thanks, @AndriiFilenko now it solved.

Comment: thanks, @TimLewis for your response